# Why does my Java print-to-paper job never get into the printer's queue?

Tags: java, printing

There are a lot of questions that deal with PrinterJobs in the printer's queue and not printing, but I haven't found a discussion of print jobs never getting into the queue.

My test program (see code below--two classes PrintIt, which is the Printable, and Report, which is a jFrame with the main) seems to run fine with no exceptions but never puts anything in the print queue.

Following the code I shall include a screen shot of the running program.

---

```html
package SVDP;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Paper;

/**
 *
 * @author Wesley Stupar
 */
public class Report extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  static Graphics g;
  static Paper pap;
  static PageFormat pf;
  static Report report;
  
  /**
   * Creates new form Report
   */
  public Report() {
    initComponents();
    g = this.getGraphics();
    pap = new Paper();
    pap.setImageableArea(36, 36, 540, 720); //1/2" margins, 8.5x11
    pf = new PageFormat();
    pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
    pf.setPaper(pap);
  }

      /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        report = new Report();
        report.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
    PrintIt printer = new PrintIt();
    if(g == null){
      System.out.println("Graphics context is null.");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    report.generate();
    try {
System.out.println("Calling print");
      printer.print(g, pf, 0);
    } catch (Exception pe) {
      System.out.println("Printer exception: "+pe);
    }
//    report.setVisible(false);
  }
  
  /**
   * Generate the page to be printed
   */
  public void generate(){
    g.drawString("Hello printer!", 100, 100);    
  }
  // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
  private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
  // End of variables declaration                   
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    package SVDP;

import java.awt.print.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;

/**
 *
 * @author Wesley Stupar
 */
public class PrintIt implements Printable {

  PrinterJob job;
  
  public PrintIt() {
    job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    if (job.printDialog()) {
      try {
        job.print();
      } catch (Exception PrintException) {
        System.out.println("PrintIt exception: "+PrintException);
      }
    }
  }
  
  @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
          PrinterException {
      job.setPrintable(this);

      if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
          return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
      }

      /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
       * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
       */
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
      g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

      /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
System.out.println("Finished print");
      return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
```

I am not allowed to post images, but I shall describe what is displayed by the program being run under NetBeans:

1. The jFrame is displayed overlaid with the print dialog. The selected printer is able to print the test page. Then the dialog is OKed. NetBeans output prints the following:
   run:
   Calling print
   Finished print
   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 12 seconds)

The program continues to run but nothing gets into the print queue. The program has to be terminated manually.

End of question.

Answer (score 0):

[After looking at this very helpful post:](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt.print/PrinterJobsetPrintablePrintablepainterPageFormatformat.htm)

I see that I was trying to render the image outside of the Printable and not instantiating the Printable correctly.